# insert into a sequelize many-to-many joint table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

how do you insert into the joint table auto generated by sequelize? my many-to-many is defined like this:

```
db.users.belongsToMany(db.groups, {through: "users_groups", foreignKey:"user_id"});
db.groups.belongsToMany(db.users, {through: "users_groups",foreignKey:"group_id"});
```

I tried simply inserting directly into users_groups with create() but it's not letting me, I looked at the sequelize doc and it seems I'm supposed to use the auto generated methods of AddUser and AddGroup, the thing is in my case, I initialized the databases in separate files so it seems sequelize is not recognizing those as methods? this is what I tried and the console log told me these are not functions

```
  User.findByPk(req.body.userId)
    .then(user=>{
      Group.findByPk(req.body.groupId).then(group=>{
        User.addGroup(group);
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, you want to add many user to a group.
This is how you would do.

```
Group.findByPK(req.body.userId)
  .then((group) => {
    group.addUsers([userId1, userId2])
   }).then((users) => console.log(users))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Just flip, if you want to add a user to multiple groups.

There are many other methods are available for a many to many instance check [here](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html).

For just overview of available all methods on a particular associated instance,  check [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#special-methods-mixins-added-to-instances).

Comment: I am just trying to create a new association, say a user has joined a group, according to the docs I should do Group.addUser(user), but it's not working and the error message says "Group.addUser is not a function"

Comment: ahh nvm got it, should be data.addGroup(data2) not User.addGroup(data2), thanks though

Answer (score 1):

solved, should be user.addGroup(group) not User.addGroup(group)